# Android Ndk debug without gradle-experimental plugin

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to configure native code debug in android studio without gradle-experimental plugin ?
I want to debug c++ code. But experimental plugin isn't option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install LLDB Plugin and Edit your run configuration and choose the debugger option to Hybrid

[Refer this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview)